# How does the Bane spell interact with critical hits?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, critical-hit

The 1st-level spell [*bane*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bane) (PHB, p. 216) allows you to curse a creature so that all of its saving throws and attack rolls are reduced by 1d4 for the duration:

> Whenever a target [...] makes an attack roll or saving throw before the spell ends, the target must roll a d4 and subtract the number rolled from the attack roll or saving throw. (PHB 216)

How does the *bane* spell interact with a natural 20 on an attack roll?

I can see two possible interpretations:

- *Bane* is stronger: A target under the effect of *bane* cannot make critical attacks, because 20 - 1d4 will always be < 20.
- Critical is stronger: A target under the effect of *bane* can make crits, since crits occur on a natural 20, and the *bane* malus is applied after determining crit.

A good answer would include relevant rules text to show how this should be handled.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

*Bane* has no bearing on a *Critical Hit*.

From page 194 of the *PHB:*

> If the d20 **roll** for an attack is a 20, the attack hits **regardless of any modifiers** or the target’s AC. In addition, the attack is a critical hit,  as explained later in this chapter.

Since a *Critical Hit* is determined by the **roll of a natural 20,** and not by the end *result* adding up to 20, any addition or subtraction (such as *Ability Modifiers* [as stated above] or spells such as *Bane*) to this roll doesn't matter, it is still a *Critical Hit.*

Also note that even if that were not the case, any creature that has +4 or higher bonus to the attack roll essentially counteracts the effects of *Bane* anyway.